# __MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile - val SiteLoginFailureException not found in section Exception

Tags: customer-community, label

I recently enabled the Global Header in a sandbox (using Classic). When switching to the Community, the user should be redirected to a custom VF page, `/CommunityHome`.

Logged in as a System Administrator, I am able to see the `CommunityHome` fine when toggling using the Global Header.

However, when logged in with another non-Administrator Profile, I receive the following error when I toggle to the Community. The URL shows `https://myorg.cs61.force.com/CommunityHome`, so the redirect is working properly for this Profile and the error occurs when rendering the redirected VF page.

[image]

I have tried the following.

- Full search of all metadata for the term `SiteLoginFailureException` and received no results.
- Added a Custom Label with Value and Name = `SiteLoginFailureException`
- Enabled the VF page, and all other VF pages that might be relevant, for the Profile
- Added the Profile to the Community

Online there is only [one](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BaksIAC) reference to this error, which is unanswered. There are other results containing the term `__MISSING LABEL__` but they are not relevant, such as classes needing recompilation.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved after some time with Salesforce support.

The root cause was that the Apex class (in this case the VF controller) was not enabled for the Profile of the affected user (Profile -> Apex Class Access).

However, the problem was ultimately resolved by using Developer mode in the browser, and support observed 404 errors in the logs when pulling up the page with the error. Unfortunately I am no longer able to reproduce the problem to provide screenshots.

EDIT 22-Mar-2019:

This problem came up again when we tried to apply the solution to a different Profile. There were two Communities in this sandbox, one with the root URL `myorg--sb.cs61.my.salesforce.com/` and another with `myorg--sb.cs61.my.salesforce.com/CommunityHome`. The first Community had `/CommunityHome` set as its default page, so in this test org we effectively had two Communities pointing at the same URL.

In this scenario the User accessing the Community must be on a Profile that is a member of both Communities, *even if* one of them is inactive.

I solved the problem by changing the home page of the secondary Community to `/SomethingElse`.

Answer (score 0):

There are whole slew of Known issues that are similar to the one you've encountered. **Some of which are still not fixed**.

> Looking at nature of the exception I would encourage you to open a
>   case with salesforce support.

**Reference:**  [Known Issues with keyword MISSING LABEL__ PropertyFile](https://success.salesforce.com/search?type=Issues&keywords=MISSING%20LABEL__%20PropertyFile)

Comment: Thank you, I have not seen a known issue for this specific error message. However I have opened a ticket with Support and perhaps mine belongs on that list too.

That said, the link I originally posted is from 2016, so this is not new, and it pertains to accessing a Community from the Global Header, which I imagine is a relatively well-utilized feature. And it only applies to some users. So it's well within the realm of possibility that it's an error specific to my org.